# What does "her mouth was the thinnest of thin lines" imply?

Tags: meaning

> It was Professor McGonagall, and **her mouth was the thinnest of thin lines**.

I don't quite get what the expression "*her mouth was the thinnest of thin lines*" conveys. Is it angry, strict or something?

Comment: "The thinnest of thin"  is like "very, very thin". Whatever emotion causes one to tense the lip muscles into a straight line.  You'd have to rely on context to determine the emotion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angry. Imagine something like below. The lips are closed tightly to form a thin line.

[image: man's mouth]

[image: angry woman pointing]

Comment: But the facial gesture is not necessarily angry (even if McGonagall happens to be). Some form of grimness. Determination would also fit.